# Rails: delayed_job on an after_create callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

Is there a way to use the `delayed_job` gem to run an `after_create` model callback function in the background?

I have a `private` function used as a callback `after_create :get_geolocation` that runs after a user signs up.

**How could I configure the model to run that in the background?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to enqueue a delayed_job task from an ActiveRecord callback. To [install and use delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#installation):

1. Add `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'` to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`.
2. Create the delayed_job support tables in your database by running:

   `rails generate delayed_job:active_record`

   `rake db:migrate`
3. In your model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :get_geolocation, on: :create

  private

  def get_geolocation
  end

  handle_asynchronously :get_geolocation
end
```

Notice that you should [use `after_commit` instead of `after_create` to schedule your job](http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2012/11/use-after_commit-instead-of-active-record-callbacks-to-avoid-unexpected-errors), so you avoid situations where the job executes before the transaction is committed.

Comment: There is one problem with the `after_commit` -- it causes delayed_job to create TWO duplicate jobs. Not sure why. While `after_create` makes a single job as expected.

Comment: Any idea why using `after_commit` creates duplicate jobs?

Comment: That's strange. Did you remember to add the `on: :create` bit? Without an `on:` argument, `after_commit` will fire its callback on *all* commit events, so that's one idea.

Comment: Another option is to wrap the code that's creating your models in a transaction manually (`MyModel.transaction do ... end`) to ensure that it all happens within a single transaction.

Comment: Yeah I had the `on: :create`. Not sure why that created duplicates. Very strange.

Comment: Hmmm. Check your `development.log` output -- are there multiple transactions happening during the controller action that creates your models?

Comment: I had an issue where the background job wouldn't fire.  But once I added it as a "private" method, it fired properly.